# Huffman-code in python doesn't work as it should

Tags: python, huffman-code

i was given the code below from one of my professors. i have it aligned the way it should be i suppose, but the problem is the code doesn't work the way it should. i can't understand why. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
import sys
codes = {}
def frequency (str):
    freqs = {}
    for ch in str :
        freqs[ch] = freqs.get(ch,0) + 1
    return freqs


def sortFreq (freqs) :
    letters = freqs.keys()
    tuples = []
    for let in letters :
        tuples.append((freqs[let],let))
    tuples.sort()
    return tuples


def buildTree(tuples) :
    while len(tuples) > 1 :
        leastTwo = tuple(tuples[0:2]) # get the 2 to combine
        theRest = tuples[2:] # all the others
        combFreq = leastTwo[0][0] + leastTwo[1][0] # the branch points freq
        tuples = theRest + [(combFreq,leastTwo)] # add branch point to the end
        tuples.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0], reverse=False) # sort it into place
    return tuples[0] # Return the single tree inside the list


def trimTree (tree) :
# Trim the freq counters off, leaving just the letters
    p = tree[1] # ignore freq count in [0]
    if type(p) == type("") : return p # if just a leaf, return it
    else : return (trimTree(p[0]), trimTree(p[1])) # trim left then right and recombine


def assignCodes (node, pat='') :
    global codes
    if type(node) == type("") :
        codes[node] = pat # A leaf. set its code
    else : #
        assignCodes(node[0], pat+"0") # Branch point. Do the left branch
        assignCodes(node[1], pat+"1") # then do the right branch.


def encode (str) :
    global codes
    output = ""
    for ch in str : output += codes[ch]
    return output


def decode (tree, str) :
    output = ""
    p = tree
    for bit in str :
        if bit == '0' : p = p[0] # Head up the left branch
        else : p = p[1] # or up the right branch
        if type(p) == type("") :
            output += p # found a character. Add to output
            p = tree # and restart for next character
    return output


def main () :
    debug = True
    str_init = sys.stdin.read()
    str = str_init[0:len(str_init)-1]
    freqs = frequency(str)
    tuples = sortFreq(freqs)
    tree = buildTree(tuples)
    if debug : print("Built tree", tree)
    tree = trimTree(tree)

    if debug : print("Trimmed tree", tree)
    assignCodes(tree)

    if debug : print(codes)
    small = encode(str)
    original = decode (tree, small)
    print("Original text length", len(str))

    print("Requires %d bits. (%d bytes)" % (len(small), (len(small)+7)/8))
    print("Restored matches original", str == original)

if __name__ == "__main__" : main()
```

The code above when i call the file through command line will let me write the phrase i want to process but when i hit enter there is no answer at all. I was told in the comments to add specific input and desired output of this code. So there it is, input  "hello" and desire output

```
Built tree (5, ((2, ((1, 'e'), (1, 'h'))), (3, ((1, 'o'), (2, 'l')))))
Trimmed tree (('e', 'h'), ('o', 'l'))
{'e': '00', 'h': '01', 'o': '10', 'l': '11'}
Original text length 5
Requires 10 bits. (2 bytes)
Restored matches original True
```

Comment: Please say what this code is supposed to do. Add a input and desired output. Don't just dump code and ask for someone to fix it.

Comment: is this ok now ? i need to add something else ? thank you for your comment by the way.

Comment: `sys.stdin.read()` reads until end-of-file. That's not the same as end-of-line, and at an interactive console, it may be _never_. Use `readline()` or just use `input()` instead.

Comment: i did use input() and the output was 
```Built tree (4, ((2, 'l'), (2, ((1, 'e'), (1, 'h')))))
Trimmed tree ('l', ('e', 'h'))
{'l': '0', 'e': '10', 'h': '11'}
Original text length 4
Requires 6 bits. (1 bytes)
Restored matches original True ```

i also did change the ```str = str_init[0:len(str_init)-1]``` into 
```str = str_init[0:len(str_init)]``` and worked completely fine. thank you very much for your help.